# Check isset for specifc value

Tags: php, isset

I got a login file which when the user logged in checks if the user is an admin.
If so it will set a value like this:

```
$_SESSION['isAdmin_logged_in'] = $isAdmin;
```

If the user is an admin this is set to true and if not to false.
However, when I try to check the isset on the admin page It won't work with

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['isAdmin_logged_in']) == 'true') { die("Admin only"); }
```

Is it even possible to check an isset for a specific value?

Comment: no, that is not possible - [isset](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) determines if a variable is declared and different from null. you can use: `if ($_SESSION['isAdmin_logged_in'] != 'true') { die("Admin only"); }`

Comment: ...or break it up into 2 separate statements. Consult the duplicate.

Comment: I figured it out!

if (!isset($_SESSION['isadmin_logged']) || $_SESSION['isadmin_logged'] != 'true')
{
    die('Admin only area! <a href="logout.php">Abmelden</a>');
}

works fine